# three.js 2d and 3d vertices interconversion

Tags: three.js

see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/guzuomuse/ze82q65k/);

```
init();

var camera, scene, renderer;

function init() {
  container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  var camera_cylinder_setting = '[0.9985033869743347, 0.02076610177755356, 0.05059404298663139, 0, 0.0047478810884058475, 0.8886997103691101, -0.4584651291370392, 0, -0.05448344349861145, 0.4580191969871521, 0.8872711062431335, 0, -0.5448344349861145, 4.5801920890808105, 8.872710227966309, 1]';

  camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(512 / -2, 512 / 2, 512 / 2, 512 / -2, -512, 512);
  camera.matrix.fromArray(JSON.parse(camera_cylinder_setting));
  camera.matrix.decompose(camera.position, camera.quaternion, camera.scale);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setClearColor(0xf0f0f0);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(512, 512);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(118, 158, 383, 30, 30, true, 3.3, 6.3);
  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: Math.random() * 0xffffff,
    opacity: 0.5
  }));
  object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
  loader.load('https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8829/28748679526_16d6e56b84_b.jpg', function(texture) {
    texture.offset = new THREE.Vector2(0.3, 0.1);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      overdraw: 1,
      map: texture
    });

    object.material = material;
    scene.add(object);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  });
}
```

what i want to know hwo to get the greed rectangle accordding to the raw image's red rectangle?
oppositely,how to get the red rectangel according to the green rectangle?

thank you very much!